# displaying console progressbars with multiprocesing

Tags: python, console-application, progress, python-multiprocessing

I have a modeling application I'm refining, and I'm having trouble getting real-time progressbar updates across multiple threads.

Each unit of model work is mapped to one processor:

```
Class Main():
   def run(self):
        s1 = datetime.now()
        p = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count(), maxtasksperchild=1)
        p.map(self.solve_one_cochlea, self.cochlear_list)
        p.close()
        p.join()            
        print("simulation of {} channels finished in {:0.3f}s".format(self.channels,timedelta.total_seconds(datetime.now()-s1)))
```

Inside `solve_one_cochlea`, there's a call to The Big Compute Loop.  On average, getting through all 7000 iterations of that loop takes about 45-90 seconds per thread:

```
import progressbar
 Class Worker:
      def long_running_solve:
           with progressbar.ProgressBar(max_value=7000, redirect_stdout=True) as bar:
                for j in range(7000):
                   #heavy linear algebra here
                   bar.update(j)
```

This is all well and good, but what happens is that instead of getting two or more progress bars that update in my console in real time, i get two fully-completed progress bars that **suddenly** appear when **all** instances of `solve_one_cochlea` have been completed, right before the final `print()` in `run`. This kind of defeats the point.

**What's a good way to change this code flow so my progress bars update the console dynamically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/aaren/multi_progress  does what I wanted.

This has some very strange output running in a PyCharm console, but works well in a real terminal.